# Discord Bot won't tell someone to join a voice channel, instead it just throws an error. Other parts work totally fine

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, audio-player

I've been working on this function for my Discord bot for quite a while and finally got most of it up and running, but I am running into an issue for my "Connect to a voice channel" warning.  The segment of code is as follows:

```
 @commands.command(name="play", help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def p(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            #you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
            await message.channel.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
```

Now this all seems to be working pretty well except for the "if voice_channel is None" portion.  An error keeps getting thrown saying "NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'".

I'm sure this is fairly simple and I understand the gist of the problem (obviously not the first time I've seen 'NoneType' object errors, but I just can't seem to figure out what I need to change here.

As I said previously, As long as I am in a voice channel everything works perfectly.  The bot connects, downloads, & plays the music.

Comment: `ctx.message.author.voice.channel` is failing because `ctx.message.author.voice` is `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `try:` like so:

```
@commands.command(name="play", help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def p(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        try:
            voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
        except:
            await message.channel.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
```

Answer (score 4):

If the User is not in a voice channel, Voice will be None, and thus will have no attribute "voice".

Try:

```
voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel if ctx.message.author.voice else None
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState

Comment: This also seems to have worked pretty well Hunter.  If I could select two correct answers I would!

Comment: Question because it doesn't seem to be documented, when would `voice` be not `None` and `voice.channel` be `None`? `None` is a valid value for `voice.channel`, but it seems that the conditions required for it to be `None` would cause `voice` itself to be `None`